# Bash : rewriting a file which is read in same line

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

I'm working on a bash script for partially automating router connection in command line.  This is part where I have a problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING2="ESSID"
MYPWD=$(pwd)
sudo iwlist wlan1 scan | grep $STRING2 | grep -n $STRING2 > $STRING2.txt
sed -r -e 's/\s+//g' -e 's/:ESSID//' $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt
```

The last line opens a text file, then deletes white spaces and also :ESSID's from the text file which is `$MYPWD/$STRING2.txt`. What I want to do is also write the output of `sed` to that file by piping. A previous approach was piping `grep : > $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt"` at the end such as :

```
sed -r -e 's/\s+//g' -e 's/:ESSID//' $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt | grep : > $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt"
```

But it ended up with an empty `$MYPWD/$STRING2.txt`. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Without the last piped grep, text file contains some text like this after execution:

1:___________ESSID:"somessid"

2:___________ESSID:"somessid"

3:___________ESSID:"somessid"

4:___________ESSID:"somessid"

ps: <__> stands for white space

```
#!/bin/bash
#declaring a string variable
STRING="MERHABA DUNYA"
STRING2="ESSID"
COUNTER="1"
MYPWD=$(pwd)
echo -e "Later you can check the recent networks around you from : " $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt\n"
#or MYPWD=${pwd}
#-e flag enables \n escape
echo -e $STRING2".txt is being updated\n. . .\n"
sudo iwlist wlan1 scan | grep $STRING2 | grep -n $STRING2 > $STRING2.txt # | sed -i# #s/ //g $STRING2.txt > $STRING2.txt
sed -r -e 's/\s+//g' -e 's/:ESSID//' $MYPWD"/"$STRING2".txt"
NUMLINE=$(sudo cat $MYPWD/$STRING2.txt | wc -l)
echo -e "\n. . ."
echo -e "\nThere are "$NUMLINE " visible networks\n"
```

Comment: Could you fix the quotes please? Show us the exact command in your script. What you show won't run so presumably, that's not what you're actually running. Please show us exactly what you are using.

Comment: What platform are you on?  If you have GNU sed, you can use the `-i` flag to modify a file in place.  I think the version of OSX supports that as well, but you have to provide an extension for the backup file

Comment: @terdon I've edited with the exact command

Comment: @EricRenouf GNU sed, you're right. Thanks for that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a command such as this

```
sed -e ... "datafile" >"datafile"
```

You will end up with a zero length result. The reason is that the shell sets up *stdin* and *stdout* before it executes the command. So *stdout* is sent to the file `datafile`, creating or truncating it in the process, and only then is the `sed -e ... "datafile"` run.

A common solution is something like this

```
sed -e ... "datafile" >"datafile.tmp" && mv -f "datafile.tmp" "datafile"
```

Some commands (including versions of `sed`) have the *edit in place* option:

```
sed -i.bak -e ... "datafile"
sed --in-place=.bak -e ... "datafile"
```

Comment: ...and just found that this has been also suggested in a comment. Why not make that an answer and save others unnecessary time and effort duplicating something that's already been said but lost in comments?